# Building a Flutter application for mobile and desktop

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

Recently I've found out about Flutter being able to support desktop applications as well. I'm just curious how far this technology is and if any of you had success porting your mobile apps to the desktop. If so, what was the experience like? Are desktop-specific features like windows, mouse interaction, desktop notifications, etc. supported?

Comment: I get down vote. while post my answer in another post. Do not know the reason. But, it really works

Comment: I have just developed & run UI clone of MyJio app in Windows. Project link here:
https://github.com/Jithin-Jude/flutter_my_jio_clone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was demonstrated at the Flutter Live event in December, but nothing official has been released that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter for Desktop was launched as alpha build at flutter interact 2019.
The official documentation is available at **https://flutter.dev/desktop**

The following video describes how to run your flutter app on a MacOS
You can watch the following video is you don't wanna read the docs 
**https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tEdoVuC1uQ&t=23s**

(Skip to 0:48 seconds, as slight noise occurs for few seconds)

A simple app is created using android studio and we can easily see the options available to port the code to all platforms. For example, if you create a default app using android studio, the mouse event will help you to tap on a button and increase the count.

[image]

Regarding the experience, it feels good to write a single code and port/deploy on any platform. Using VSCode or android studio, both are helpful.